# Unable to pre-warm the engine and them use it later on Android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-engine

I have an android SDK to be used by clients, the SDK has some abstractions so the clients don't have to deal with flutter bindings.

I the SDK I have something like this

```
class SDKPrivate  {
private static FlutterEngine flutterEngine;
...
 public void initFlutterEngine(Context context){
        if(SDKPrivate.flutterEngine != null) return;

        SDKPrivate.flutterEngine = new FlutterEngine(context);

        SDKPrivate.flutterEngine.getDartExecutor()
                .executeDartEntrypoint(DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault());
    }

    MyFragment createFragment() {
        return new MyFragment();
    }
...
}
```

The fragment class is

```
public class MyFragment extends FlutterFragment {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldAttachEngineToActivity() {
        return true;
    }

     @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated( savedInstanceState);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(sdkPrivate.getEngine());
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public FlutterEngine provideFlutterEngine(@NonNull Context context) {
        return sdkPrivate.getEngine();
    }
```

In the sample app that I created to do the tests, I have a main activity that does

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SDKPrivate.initFlutterEngine(getApplicationContext());
```

and it has a button that calls I new activity that will have the MyFragment inside

```
Intent activity2Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragActivity.class);
            startActivity(activity2Intent);
```

FragActivity  is like this

```
public class FragActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag);

       MyFragment  frag = SDKPrivate.createFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frame_layout, frag,  BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".MyFragment")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

When I have the code like this when I enter the FragActivity the app stays blank. **But**  if I start the engine inside the FragActivity the app works as expected.

Like this,  is ok

```
public class FragActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag);
        SDKPrivate.initFlutterEngine(getApplicationContext());
       //Same code as showed above 
      ...
}
```

Is there a reason for this? I also want to give the client a way to warm up the engine an then use it on a fragment and on an activity without creating a new one.

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B2093, locale en-PT)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/manuelpeixoto/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (6 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/manuelpeixoto/Library/Android/sdk/
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/manuelpeixoto/Library/Android/sdk/
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.2.1, Build version 11B500
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • XT1097                   • 0016256677                • android-arm • Android 6.0 (API 23)
    • iPhone  • 00008030-000A053901D0802E • ios         • iOS 13.3

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem, I had this line in my main.dart

```
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
```

That made the flutter initialization stall for some reason.

I changed it to,

```
 unawaited(SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]))
```

and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create an engine cache it for later use.
// Cache the pre-warmed FlutterEngine to be used later by FlutterFragment.
FlutterEngineCache
  .getInstance()
  .put("my_engine_id", flutterEngine);

And use it in flutter fragment as
flutterFragment.withCachedEngine("my_engine_id").build();

Comment: CachedEngine is just a different way to save flutterEngine, and the documentation says that if you want to extend FlutterFragment just override provideFlutterEngine and it should work the same.